# Can't get eclipse to run terminal command on mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, swig

I have installed swig on my mac and it works in the console just fine. If I type swig -verison in terminal it spits out the version. Eclipse keeps telling me that it can't find swig. I am using the liquidfun library http://google.github.io/liquidfun/SWIG/html/index.html and it told me to put this export SWIG_BIN=$("which" swig) in .bashrc, which I did. This enviroment variable registers through terminal as well. Eclipse STILL won't grab swig properly. What the hell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash reads `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login` or `.profile`. I don't expect the Eclipse process to load such a file (although I could be wrong) nor the SWIG_BIN variable to augment its search path for executables, but if you launch Eclipse from the shell, it should inherit the shell's environment variables.

Try running swig from eclipse using a full absolute path (the one that "which" returns).

The eclipse.ini file can set some startup parameters but perhaps not the path. There might be other eclipse startup files.

Another possibility is to add swig's directory to the path in a login script. (To test that, log out and back in, then start eclipse.)

Comment: I thought the .bash_profile worked with the terminal only and .bashrc worked with gui programs that use a terminal...?

Comment: I added the absolute path like you said and it worked. Thanks. totally annoying.

Comment: Glad that helped! Per the man page, bash as an interactive login shell reads `.bash_profile` or else `.bash_login` or else `.profile`; bash as a non-login shell reads `.bashrc`. If you launch eclipse from a shell, it should inherit that shell's environment settings, but I don't think it'll read any of these shell profile files. The eclipse.ini file can set some startup parameters but perhaps not the path.

Comment: You can run the .bash_profile 'by hand' by typing `. .bash_profile` (single dot, space, .bash_profile)